How FIR Linear phase maintained in stop band
When we see a FIR Linear phase filter upto pass band we see the phase response is linear.
But when it enters to stop band whenever there are ripples (like magnitude becoming very low)
I can see a sudden phase jump from -pi to pi


Search for "Phase unwrapping". You can start here

@Jdip regardless of the wrapping as we pass through $\pm \pi$ the phase can STILL jump by $\pi$ (180°). This occurs whenever the complex frequency response goes through the origin regardless of phase entry point. For example we could approach the origin at -90° and emerge at +90°.

There are steps in the phase, specifically when the complex frequency response passes through the origin (zero), the phase will jump by 180°.  You can see this if you simply subtract one from a continuously linearly increasing phase:
$$H(\omega) = e^{j\omega t} - 1$$
The phase is still considered to be "linear phase".  (And the system itself is linear regardless of changing the magnitude $+/-1$, but linear phase is not to be confused with a linear system; a non-linear phase filter is also a linear system!).
A linear phase filter will have a constant group delay at all frequencies except where the magnitude is zero where the group delay is not defined. The group delay is the negative derivative of phase with respect to frequency. As we can see by inspection from the OP's plot, the slope or derivative is constant everywhere (ignoring the samples where the magnitude is zero) and thus the system is "linear phase".
